# ElasticSearch 5.1.1 + Grafana 4.1.0 Time seems offset by UTC difference

Tags: elasticsearch, timezone, grafana

I'm running Grafana 4.1.0_beta1 and Elasticsearch 5.1.1.

All my servers are setup for Mountain Time, I seem to be running into an issue where Grafana attempts to "account" for UTC, and offsets search parameters by 7 hours.

As an example;

`date` result from server; `Wed Jan  4 20:10:54 MST 2017`

But when I try to add and test a data source in Grafana, I get this error:

```
{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"metricbeat-2017.01.05","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"metricbeat-2017.01.05"}],"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"metricbeat-2017.01.05","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"metricbeat-2017.01.05"}
```

While `metricbeat-2017.01.05` does not exist, `metricbeat-2017.01.04` does as it should.

When on a dashboard, I don't see any data, until I set the time, to anything over 7h prior.

I didn't see anything regarding timezone in the elasticsearch, or grafana config files.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Classic case of over analyzing.

It looked like everything was correct because it was, except for my client timezone.

1. Correct Timezone on local client
2. Ensure time is updated correctly
3. Restart web browser

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to time shift the data back into range by 7h by going into added panel widget -> Time range -> Add time shift.

--If nothing else works that is.